# Cannot install ubuntu iso file through USB stick

Tags: software-installation

I recently tried downloaded iso file of ubuntu to burn into usb flash drive, using wubi and power iso tools but when system reboots for installation, it throws error namely

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable mount root fs on unknown block(1,0)
```

Please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Kernel Panic errors comes when there is some problem in Bootable Media, due to scratch or burning problem. Try to make a bootable USB using Startup Disk Creator available in Ubuntu and boot. 
If from windows, Linux Live USB creator ;-)  Or [Pendrive Linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/).

Answer (score 0):

use [**unetbootin**](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). This works with windows and ubuntu. Visit their website you will see an instruction how to burn ubuntu iso file in usb flash drive. Unetbootin works with almost every iso file of linux os.

**Website: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/**

If you want you can use universal usb installer. See [**this link**](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) you will have the idea how to make live usb of ubuntu. Good luck.